# How to turn a point3d array from Cartesian coordinates into Spherical coordinate system?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry

How to turn a point3d array from Cartesian coordinates into Spherical coordinate system (assuming its geometric  center is 0,0,0 in spherical system)?

Comment: coordinate projection is at the very heart of GIS... you should look there

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) also has a nice article on the subject.  The 'Coordinate system conversions' sub-heading may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copying the formula from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system), apply this to each entry in the array:

```
r = Math.Sqrt(p.X*p.X + p.Y*p.Y + p.Z*p.Z);
if (r == 0) {
  theta = 0;
  phi = 0;
} else {
  theta = Math.Acos(p.Z/r);
  phi = Math.Atan2(p.Y, p.X);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's completly possible. So look here [Spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) and here [Spherical Coordinates in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18160/Spherical-Coordinates-in-C).
You can achieve what do you want reading these articles. I don't find any problem. So please, if there is something you don't understand comment.

Here is some code:

```
public Point3 Spherical(float r, float theta, float phi) 
{
    Point3 pt = new Point3();
    float snt = (float)Math.Sin(theta * Math.PI / 180); 
    float cnt = (float)Math.Cos(theta * Math.PI / 180); 
    float snp = (float)Math.Sin(phi * Math.PI / 180); 
    float cnp = (float)Math.Cos(phi * Math.PI / 180); 
    pt.X = r * snt * cnp; 
    pt.Y = r * cnt; 
    pt.Z = -r * snt * snp; 
    pt.W = 1; 
    return pt; 
}
```

Comment: What is W? xyz I get, but W?